# enter() d3.js doesn't work on a html.erb file ruby rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, d3.js

I'm trying to show a d3.js chart on a html.erb file
 this is the code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        d3.csv("app/views/incidentes/file.csv", function(data){

            var canvas= d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height",500)
            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("width", function(d){return d.cantidad*10;})
                        .attr("height", 50)
                        .attr("y", function(d, i){return i*50;})
                        .attr("fill", "blue")

        })



    </script>
```

It doesn't show the chart, I've made this code on a .html file and it goes well. 
But when I run it on my ruby app it doesn't show the chart. 
I inspected the script in firebug and it doesn't enter when .enter() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script has not permissions to access view's path:

```
d3.csv("app/views/incidentes/file.csv" ..
```

Just, move 'file.csv' to '/public' folder, and replace file path with:

```
 d3.csv("/file.csv" ...
```